# MySQL add another looked up value to SUM value

Tags: mysql, aggregate-functions

The actual application is more complicated but here is a simplified version of what I'm trying to accomplish.

I have a table that contains values that need to be summed up (ResponseValue) for each person (Staff_ID)
Table A

```
+----------+-----------+---------------+
| Staff_ID | OT_Period | ResponseValue |
+----------+-----------+---------------+
| 4        | 4         | 1             |
+----------+-----------+---------------+
| 6        | 4         | 1             |
+----------+-----------+---------------+
| 8        | 4         | 1             |
+----------+-----------+---------------+
| 2        | 4         | 1             |
+----------+-----------+---------------+
| 1        | 4         | 1             |
+----------+-----------+---------------+
| 11       | 4         | 1             |
+----------+-----------+---------------+
| 13       | 4         | 0             |
+----------+-----------+---------------+
| 45       | 4         | 1             |
+----------+-----------+---------------+
| 57       | 4         | 1             |
+----------+-----------+---------------+
| 63       | 4         | 1             |
+----------+-----------+---------------+
| 1        | 4         | 1             |
+----------+-----------+---------------+
| 2        | 4         | 1             |
+----------+-----------+---------------+
| 4        | 4         | 1             |
+----------+-----------+---------------+
| 6        |           |               |
+----------+-----------+---------------+
| 8        | 4         | 1             |
+----------+-----------+---------------+
| 11       | 4         | 1             |
+----------+-----------+---------------+
| 13       | 4         | 1             |
+----------+-----------+---------------+
| 45       | 4         | 1             |
+----------+-----------+---------------+
| 57       | 4         | 1             |
+----------+-----------+---------------+
| 63       | 4         | 0             |
+----------+-----------+---------------+
```

I have a second table that contains an adjustment value for each Staff_ID and OT_Period
Table B

```
+----------+-----------+------------+
| Staff_ID | OT_Period | Adjustment |
+----------+-----------+------------+
| 1        | 4         | 2          |
+----------+-----------+------------+
| 11       | 4         | 1          |
+----------+-----------+------------+
| 13       | 4         | 0          |
+----------+-----------+------------+
| 45       | 4         | 5          |
+----------+-----------+------------+
| 57       | 4         | 4          |
+----------+-----------+------------+
| 63       | 4         | 2          |
+----------+-----------+------------+
```

My MySQL query succeeds at summing the values in the first table into a column called "ShiftCount" but ShiftCount goes to Null when I try to add the adjustment value to it.

The expected result would be

```
+----------+------------+
| Staff_ID | ShiftCount |
+----------+------------+
| 1        | 4          |
+----------+------------+
| 2        | 2          |
+----------+------------+
| 4        | 2          |
+----------+------------+
| 6        | 1          |
+----------+------------+
| 8        | 2          |
+----------+------------+
| 11       | 3          |
+----------+------------+
| 13       | 1          |
+----------+------------+
| 45       | 7          |
+----------+------------+
| 57       | 6          |
+----------+------------+
| 63       | 3          |
+----------+------------+
```

My working Query to get the sum is

```
SELECT a.Staff_ID, a.OT_PeriodID, COALESCE(SUM(ResponseValue),0) AS ShiftCount
FROM TableA a
GROUP BY a.Staff_ID
```

I tried the following and this makes all the "ShiftCount" values Null

```
SELECT a.Staff_ID, a.OT_PeriodID, COALESCE(SUM(ResponseValue),0)+Adjustment AS ShiftCount
FROM TableA a
LEFT JOIN TableB b
ON a.Staff_ID=b.Staff_ID
GROUP BY a.Staff_ID
```

What am I missing?  Thanks!

Comment: You need to convert the `NULL` in Adjustment to 0.  Also I don't think your query will work because it's not in `GROUP BY`.

Comment: I only get `ShiftCount = NULL` when there's no row in TableB, because you need `COALESCE(Adjustment, 0)`

Comment: You also need to put `OT_Period` into the `GROUP BY`, or use an aggregation function around it.

Comment: query seems fine. gruoping by staff_Id is enough as that is the only unique field

Comment: Your question is not clear. We don't know the keys in the tables. We don't know how the tables are related. We don't know what you actually want to add. We can only guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the each adjustment is made against Staff_ID+OT_Period pair:

```
SELECT a.Staff_ID, ifnull(SUM(a.ResponseValue),0)+ifnull(b.Adjustment, 0) AS ShiftCount
FROM TableA a
  LEFT JOIN TableB b ON a.Staff_ID=b.Staff_ID and a.OT_Period=b.OT_Period
GROUP BY a.Staff_ID, b.Adjustment
```

Comment: Works almost identical to your solution, I just used COALESCE in place of ifnull.  I was also missing the AND condition in the JOIN.  Without that, it added the adjustment regardless of the "OT_Period".  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you add the expression "COALESCE" to the column Adjustment doesnt work?

Also i think you need to add "a.OT_PeriodID" and "Adjustment" into the GROUP BY.

Try this way:

```
SELECT a.Staff_ID, COALESCE(SUM(ResponseValue),0)+COALESCE(Adjustment,0) AS ShiftCount FROM TableA a LEFT JOIN TableB b ON a.Staff_ID=b.Staff_ID GROUP BY a.Staff_ID, Adjustment
```

Comment: I thought this worked at first.  I just realized that it was adding the adjustment regardless of the OT_Period.  Once I added the AND condition in the join that @slaakso mentioned in the other answer, it worked.  Thank you.